# Inserting variable into registry path

Tags: windows, registry, command-prompt

Im trying to the add the `main` program into my system startup using only variables. I've tried doing this:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /V "My App" /t REG_SZ /F /D "C:%path%"
```

but I get a syntax error

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: to execute this you need admin permissions. Try to run the cmd 'as administrator'

Comment: Thats not the issue the issue is Im trying to insert the `%path%` in but am getting an error

Comment: what's the exact error message?